# google search as an rss feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss

Is there a way to have treat google serach results as an rss feed?

For example say I worked for stackoverflow and wanted to montior how if the results from the following search url: `http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=stackoverflow` changes from day today.

It would be cool if I could append `&output=rss` to the url and get back a feed like with google news.  But that does not seem to be supported.

Anyone have ideas? (Note I am programing with Ruby and Rails, if that matters)

Thanks!

Jonathan

Comment: +1 for cool question, but I'm not sure this is programming related.

Comment: @JohnWeldon dont be splitting hairs mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has the [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) service, which notifies you whenever it finds new content matching a certain query. Besides sending to an email address (instantly, daily, weekly), it allows you to create an RSS feed out of it.

Answer (score 0):

No, Google doesn't offer that feature.
If you need to parse/convert the result of a query on Google, you can use a (X)HTML parser such as [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Beware that automatic requests to Google may violate its TOS.